# Assigning an interface inside a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have this fragment that has an interface so i could relay other events to other fragments.

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    private MyListener mListener;

    public interface MyListener {
        public void doSomething(View o);
    }
}
```

Then I use this on a button

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       mListener.doSomething(v);       
    }
});
```

But it returns null since it's not assigned. So how do I assign my interface on the current fragment?

and what if I want to implement this on another fragment? Is this possible?

```
public class AnotherFragment extends Fragment implements MyFragment.MyListener {
    @Override
    public void doSomething(View o){}      
}
```

Comment: `mListener= (MyListener) activity;` do in `onAttach(..)`  in `Fragment`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    @Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
    // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
    try {
        mListener= (MyListener ) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement MyListener ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use onAttach() method for this. 
From Google's Fragment guide:

```
public static class MyFragment extends Fragment {
MyListener mListener;
...
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    mListener = (MyListener) activity;    // <-- For this to work, you need to implement your interface in the activity
}
...
}
```

Also dont forget to null out reference in onDetach() like this

```
@Override
public void onDetach() {
  super.onDetach();
  mListener = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your `mListener` is null -> must be create . 
To use interface:

```
AnotherFragment abc = new AnotherFragment ();
mListener = abc;
```

and then you can call : `mListener.doSomething(v)`